# iPhone:Can't tap UILabel at specified frame using UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone

I am used UITapGestureRecognizer in my apps but I can't to tap on the UILabel only so please help to solve this problem and I want to redirect on next view controller click on e  letter of UILabel so please help me .......

```
  self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 48, 94, 21)];
  self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  self.label.text = @"I like iPhone";

recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapFrom:)];
  [self.label addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
  [self.view addSubview:label];
   self.tapRecognizer = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
   recognizer.delegate = self;
   [recognizer release];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try setting the userInteractionEnabled property of the label to YES...

Comment: ok thanks a lot but also I want to redirect on next view controller click on e letter of UILabel so please help me ....... any idea?

Comment: obtain the coordintes of tat point where E is located using touchesBegan method and the implement the pushViewController method accordingly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UILabel by default does not allow user interaction - you must explicitly enable it:

```
self.label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: ok thanks a lot but also I want to redirect on next view controller click on e letter of UILabel so please help me ....... any idea?

Comment: If you don't need any special effects you can just put transparent UIButton over appropriate part of your label - label's frame is rather small so there's no point to create precise button frame as touch area will be larger anyway

Comment: thanks a lot Is there any way to set frame according to label text??any idea?

Comment: There's sizeWithFont: functions family in NSString's UIKit extension. You can try to calculate frame of 'e' letter by calculating size of text before it and then size of text with it

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable user interaction for a label, it is disabled by default.

```
self.label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```